# Angular momentum equation

Tags: angular-momentum, celestial-mechanics

The equation you provided, $(S_{\text{Axial}} = \frac{\omega}{M_{\text{System}} \times M_{\text{External}}})$, has several implications related to angular momentum and rotational dynamics:

Angular Momentum Conservation:
The equation highlights the conservation of angular momentum in a system.
When no external torques act on a closed system, the total angular momentum remains constant.
If the moment of inertia of the system changes (e.g., by redistributing mass), the angular velocity adjusts to maintain the same total angular momentum.
Role of Moment of Inertia:
The moment of inertia ((I)) represents an object’s resistance to changes in rotational motion.
Objects with larger moments of inertia require more torque to change their angular velocity.
The equation emphasizes that the system’s moment of inertia $((M_{\text{System}}))$ affects its angular momentum.
External Objects’ Influence:
The term $(M_{\text{External}})$ refers to the moment of inertia of external objects.
External objects (such as planets, satellites, or other masses) influence the system’s angular momentum.
Their distribution of mass affects the overall behavior of the system.
Application to Celestial Bodies:
In celestial mechanics, this equation is relevant for planets, moons, and other rotating bodies.
For example, Earth’s rotation affects its angular momentum, which interacts with the Moon’s gravitational pull.
Astrophysical Phenomena:
The equation plays a role in understanding phenomena like planetary precession, spin-orbit coupling, and the stability of rotating systems.

Comment: Where is your question?

Comment: Thank you Ghoster

Comment: Are you trying to post an answer or a question? Your first sentence is referring to "[t]he equation you provided..." The equation **who** provided? Are you responding to someone else?

Comment: You have five subsections. Shouldn’t they each be a paragraph? Subsections like these, each introduced by a colon-terminated phrase, are a hallmark of chatbot-generated answers. Did you use one?

Comment: The initial equation appears to be nonsense, as does some of the text. These are also hallmarks of chatbots.

Comment: I wasn't privately given a reason why my question was closed

Comment: That’s not how this site works. The reason is stated in the public closure message above your post. It includes a link. Did you read it?